# Units and Measurements in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, measurement

I am trying to make a measurement entry keyboard class that has a text field for the value, and a picker for the unit.

I am having trouble using the Measurement type because of its generic behaviour.

I would like my class to return a new Measurement instance based on the initial value, but allowing the user to change the unit without necessarily converting it. I get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Unit' to expected argument type 'T'" on the line where I am initialising meas with a value, and a unit of a different type.

Also, is there an way to iterate through the built-in sub units of a Dimension Type? i.e get all the sub units of UnitPressure for example.

If someone could just point me to an answer about similar generic behaviour, that would be much appreciated.

```
class MeasurementPicker<T : Dimension> {
    
    init(initialUnit: Measurement<T>) {
        self.initUnit = initialUnit
    }
    
    var initUnit: Measurement<T>
    
    func getUnitList() -> [Unit]? {
        switch initUnit.unit.self {
        case is UnitPressure:
            let retUnits: [Unit]? = [
                UnitPressure.bars,
                UnitPressure.gigapascals,
                UnitPressure.hectopascals,
                UnitPressure.inchesOfMercury,
                UnitPressure.kilopascals,
                UnitPressure.megapascals,
                UnitPressure.millibars,
                UnitPressure.millimetersOfMercury,
                UnitPressure.newtonsPerMetersSquared,
                UnitPressure.poundsForcePerSquareInch
            ]
            return retUnits
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    func getNewType(index: Int) -> Measurement<T> {
        let myNewUnit : Unit = getUnitList()![index]
        var meas = Measurement<T>.init(value: 6, unit: myNewUnit)

    }
    
}

let x = Measurement(value: 5.5, unit: UnitPressure.kilopascals)
let y = MeasurementPicker<UnitPressure>(initialUnit: x)
let z = y.getNewType(index: 0)
print(z.unit.symbol)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to create a generic class. Just create a unit or dimension property. And in your method getNewType return `Measurement<Unit>` or just the unit or the dimension. You can also just use a subscript to get the dimension from your list:

```
class MeasurementPicker {
    init(dimension: Dimension) { self.dimension = dimension }
    var dimension: Dimension
    var list: [Dimension] {
        switch dimension.self {
        case is UnitPressure:
            return [UnitPressure.bars,
                    UnitPressure.gigapascals,
                    UnitPressure.hectopascals,
                    UnitPressure.inchesOfMercury,
                    UnitPressure.kilopascals,
                    UnitPressure.megapascals,
                    UnitPressure.millibars,
                    UnitPressure.millimetersOfMercury,
                    UnitPressure.newtonsPerMetersSquared,
                    UnitPressure.poundsForcePerSquareInch]
        default: return []
        }
    }

}
```

---

Usage:

```
let y = MeasurementPicker(dimension: UnitPressure.kilopascals)
let z = y.list[0]
print(z.symbol)   // "bar\n"
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Leo. I have not framed my question real well though. I want to then instantiate a new Measurement<T> object with T being a type returned from the list.. say index 0. Is this possible? I suppose my real question should be can I instantiate a generic type with a stored parameter type. I can see now that the containing class dose not need to be generic. Thanks for that.